# Property of Conditionally Convergent series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $ \sum a_n$ be an conditionally convergent series.For any real number R, is it true that there exists a sequence$\{b_n\}$ where each $b_i=1 $ or $-1$ such that $\sum a_nb_n$ converges to R?

Comment: This uses the same ideas as the proof of the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem.